# HPUX setacl leaves uid behind

Tags: permissions, acl, hp-ux

I have a shell script that I execute after uninstalling a web application.  The script is meant to clean up permissions that were needed during the execution of the application.

`find /opt/path -exec setacl -d user:myUser {} ';'`

After this executes and the acl is removed  I am left with an acl that looks as follows

`user:101:--- /opt/path`

How can I properly call `setacl` to remove the user without leaving behind a uid?

Comment: Can you show the output from `getacl /opt/path` before you run anything, and then afterwards too?  Plus the output of `ls -ld /opt/path` both before and after too.  That way, there's a chance we'll see what's changed.  What was the UID of myUser?

Comment: @Jonathan the UID was 101 of the user, I am not sure if that is coincidental

Answer (score 3):

If you've quoted your command accurately as:

```
find /opt/path -exec setacl -d user:myUser{} ';'
```

you are missing a crucial space:

```
find /opt/path -exec setacl -d user:myUser {} ';'
```

The former invokes undefined (or maybe implementation-defined) behaviour from `find`; it might or might not expand the file name when the `{}` is not in an argument on its own.  But it then invokes the `setacl` command with no filename; it combines the filename with the control argument `user:myUser`.

It is most unlikely to be correct as written - but I'm hoping that it is just a typo in your transcription from your system to SO.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed, but if the missing space was a problem, I think there would be an error from `setacl`, or it would do nothing.

Comment: Yeah - I think we can treat it as a transcription error.  On a HP-UX machine, running `$setacl -d user:101$PWD` generated `unknown user-id "101/u/jleffler"`.  So, technically an accurate answer, but not really the help the question needed.

Comment: Oops typo on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Is user 101 the owner of the file? If so, you need to change the file to a different user ID, with `chown` (in addition to, or in lieu of, the `setacl` call). Every file belongs to one user and one group; ACLs come in addition to that.

Note that I've never used ACLs on HP/UX, so I may be missing something.

It might help if you showed the output of `ls -ld /opt/path` and `getacl /opt/path` before you run that `find` command.

Comment: root:sys as owner:group